# Copy/paste menu translation into swedish content in UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, localization

[image]

I am building an application for a Swedish client. We didnt do any changes to the project setup and developed the application in xcode. The client is right now coming back and pointing that the "copy / paste" dialog box that comes up in the UISearchBar is also in English. They want this to be in Swedish. Can you please let me know on where this change/ setting needs to be implemented?

Comment: I am experiencing the same : http://stackoverflow.com/q/11224969/598857