# Xcode 4.4 IOS localization

Tags: cocoa-touch, localization

In my IOS project I must do the localization of NSLocalizedStrings to other languages in all .h and .m files. What is the most correct way to do this in latest Xcode 4.4 (Montain Lion) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224969/localizing-the-cutcopypaste-menu-on-ios/11282184#11282184

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Localization is the same on Mac as on iOS. You use NSLocalizedString and translate your .strings files.

Comment: When i first time tried Xcode(it was 3.2 version) it created folders like en.proj, de.proj for example with .strings files inside. Now when I am adding new localizations Xcode creates .strings file inside of InfoPlist.strings. So is it okay, or I do something wrong?

Comment: I don't understand. How can Xcode create a file _inside_ an other one? Doesn't make sense. InfoPlist.strings is a localizable version of your Info.plist file. You don't use that to localize your app. Add a Localizable.strings file (if there is none yet) and make it localizable (on the right side in Xcode).

Comment: Yeah, that's just the localizations of that file. If you look in Finder, you'll see that those files are in separate folders (en.lproj etc.). Don't bother with those.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer Ray Wenderlich Tutorial for localization http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial