# cut/copy/paste functionality stopped working in my iOS application

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield, copy-paste

UPDATE: cut/copy/paste disabled in my app.

I am confused with my iOS app while developing for iPhone devices. Execution flow enters a point like the code below

```
[self navigationController] pushViewController:chooseDeviceView animated:YES];
[chooseDeviceView release];             
[numberTextField setText:@""];
```

The view changes and things "work properly". The problem is that after this the cut/copy/paste functionality is missing in my app.

Don't really know how to start debugging the issue. Does it ring a bell to anybody?

Comment: What's the layout of your buttons & chooseDeviceView in your view?

Comment: visite this one :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224969/localizing-the-cutcopypaste-menu-on-ios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was a very complicated issue for a beginner. Finally the issue was a little bit related with [status message corrupts main window in my iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874174/status-message-corrupts-main-window-in-my-iphone-app)

Answer (score 0):

Add in your new viewController this:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}
```

It should solve your issue.