# UIDatepicker returns wrong value

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uidatepicker

my UIDatepicker returns a wrong value and I don´t understand why. See picture.
It shows **0 hours** and **1 min** but the label shows **-1 hour**.
I don´t find an time zone to set up. I expected that my app uses the time zone of the machine it´s on.

My action to fill the label:

```
- (IBAction)datePickerDateChanged:(id)sender {
   [_timerOutput setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [_timePicker date]]];
}
```

I´m on a German system and I set the UIDatepicker to German but it still shows **hours** and **mins**.

Any idea what I´m doing wrong?

Ronald

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the date and time in GMT wintertime (== UTC). use a NSDateFormatter to adjust it, it should use the default timezone by default. you also can set another.

try

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
NSString *myDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: [_timePicker date]];
NSLog(@"%@", myDateString);
```

---

*Some theory:*

A NSDate object does not represent what we call a date in every-days sense, like a day or a time of range, or what ever. It represents a single point in time. with sub-millisecond precision.  And it does so by counting time intervals. From the beginning of a certain era. and by definition it is keeping UTC timezone as reference.
The internal counter will always be counting in UTC-context, it is your responsibility to display it correctly. But the NSDateFormatter is of huge help for that.
BTW: That your displayed time is a UTC time formatted one is also shown by `+0000`, as it has 00 hours and 00 minutes timezone offset from UTC.

Comment: Great explanation, I understand, Tal :)

Comment: Vielleicht noch ne Idee, warum hours und min in English erscheint? Ich habe DR und FR Versionen angelegt

Comment: What steps did u perform to localize your app?

Comment: I created the languages for MainStoryboard_iPad.storyboard and chose the proper language in Attributes Manager.

Comment: did u do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224969/localizing-the-cutcopypaste-menu-on-ios/11282184#11282184