# Change language used in copy/paste menu to something other than English

Tags: ios, localization, uimenucontroller

I have set "Localization native development region" to "France" in my Info.plist. Nevertheless, the copy/paste menu on a `UITextField` is still in English. I do not understand why, and I guess the app is still in English.

What setting do I need to change to make this menu use French?

Comment: Your copy/paste menu will be in whatever language you have chosen for the device. Read more about [Internationalization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Localizing the Cut|Copy|Paste menu on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224969/localizing-the-cutcopypaste-menu-on-ios)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a solution for this problem.
when you run app by Developer, It will show english.
But When apple review it, It will change follow language device.

I can set language Developer in Info.plist

CFBundleDevelopmentRegion
ja

Answer (score 3):

Found this was set by 'Localization native development region' in 'Info.plist'

You could find it by clicking the target and select 'Info' tab

Comment: I have set this already and it still did not work. Additionally, I added the "Localization" property in Info.plist, changed the language, and all items were "translated" to the selected language

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are talking about this menu:

[image: copy menu]

The language for this menu is set by your *device's* language - not your development language.

Comment: Really ? My iPhone is set in French . . . May be it's only in dev state ?

Comment: @user2206906 I believe so - you are sure it's in English for you?

Comment: Yea i have a app that i have submitted which is available in the app store, my iPhone is in French, app store is set for France and i still i have english in this menu, i would like no to do the same in this new app !