# How to add a new language to Settings Bundle

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have added a SettingsBundle via New File->Settings Bundle but i have only english. but german localization in my Bundle. The project has german as "root"-localization.

here a screen what i mean:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224969/localizing-the-cutcopypaste-menu-on-ios/11282184#11282184

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some defined folder names for different languages. For ex - en.lproj for english.
Add the files you want to add for that language.

You can localize images also using that.
Copy settings file in that folder. And add a reference to your project. Localize file from story board on right hand side.

This will work.

Comment: i have created the 2 folders for the localizations in another directory than root. So i think this is my issue. I will delete my localization files and build the new in the default folder. I have, in this in pre alpha, only eighth translations.  i will try it tomorrow.