# Copy/Paste cursor language in textfield

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want to change the language of copy/paste cursor (and other: select all...) to french, I did some search about localization and internationalization, but I don't know if I'm in the good way.

Comment: I'm on the device in the others app the langage is ok its only on my apps that I have english @EricD.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224969/localizing-the-cutcopypaste-menu-on-ios check this link

Answer (score 1):

Edit the info.plist file and set the Localization native development region